# How do I make 2 PWA's under same root domain

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a folder under which I have 2 react apps.

app 1 - abc.com

app 2 - abc.com/Shop

currently, when I am installing any one of the PWA by adding to the homescreen, it doesn't show the add to the homescreen for the other app.

app 1 manifest -

```
{
  "short_name": "abc",
  "name": "abc",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

app 2 manifest

```
{
    "short_name": "abc shop",
    "name": "abc shop",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
            "type": "image/x-icon"
        },
        {
            "src": "logo192.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
            "src": "logo512.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        }
    ],

    "start_url": "https://abc.in/Shop",
    "scope": "/shop-user/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#000000",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

How should I set up my manifest soo that if I install app 1 and then go to app 2 still it should show for add to the home screen popup